# Invalid font error while compiling LaTex document on Mac

Tags: macos, fonts, latex, tex, xelatex

I'm trying to compile a LaTex document on Mac for the first time. Previously I only ever compiled the document on Windows using TeXstudio. I installed MacTex and installed the custom fonts my document uses - specifically the "Fontin" family. My .tex file uses fontspec to control fonts.

I have 4 .otf files for the fonts and I have installed them to my system via Font Book.

After some experimentation I discovered that I need to use the `xelatex` command to compile the .tex file to a .pdf. However, while it appears to make some progress, I am always getting the following error:

```
$ xelatex doc.tex
...
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (12)
```

I'm not sure how I might avoid this error to be able to compile the document. Should I install the font from a format other than .otf on Mac? Or will I need to use a completely different font that is Mac-compatible?

I checked the .log output file but the contents didn't seem particularly helpful. I see in the logs that the fontspec package is loaded and it prints:

```
Package fontspec Info: Font family 'Fontin-Regular.otf(1)' created for font
(fontspec)             'Fontin-Regular.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFont=Fontin-Sma
llCaps.otf].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[Fontin-Regular.otf]/OT:language=dflt;mapping=tex-te
xt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[Fontin-SmallCaps.otf]/OT:language=dflt;mapping=tex-
text;"
```

However this does not mention the Fontin-Italic.otf flavour - maybe that is the problematic one?

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question - I figured out in the end it had nothing to do with the Fontin font, but this statement in my .tex source file:

```
\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command
```

I originally copied this from somewhere else so I cannot remember exactly what it is doing, but it seems to be defining a new Font to render "LaTeX" in a fancy way. No idea why it works on Windows but not on Mac but removing this (and the subsequent usage of \fb) makes everything work as expected.

Comment: cmr10 is the Computer Modern font. By the comment, the author preferred it to render the LaTeX symbol